# How do I change the dimensions of a PCB in Altium Designer 19.1 using by entering the value I want the dimension to be?

Tags: pcb, altium

How do I change the dimensions of a PCB in Altium Designer 19.1 using by entering the value I want the dimension to be?

Please for the love of 555 DO NOT tell me how to edit the size using the mouse OR by editing the grid snap size. I want to actually define the width and length of a rectangular PCB.

EDIT: Clarification: What I meant when I said do not tell me how to edit using the mouse is that I didn't want someone to tell me I can click and drag the board edges to resize (as this is a very inaccurate way set dimensions). A good example of what I want to do can be taken from SolidWorks, in Solidworks when you can type in the value (mm, inches, etc) of the line you've just clicked on to define its length. That's what I want to do except for the width and length of a PCB.

Comment: Haven't used 19. My practice in 16 is to draw the board outline on mechanical layer 1 and then use "Design" : "Board Shape" : "Define from selected objects". Please for the love of 555 don't be angry if this doesn't help you. It sounds like you are being awfully particular about how you want to define the board size, and maybe it is not possible to do it exactly that way. Also, FYI, you can put lines wherever you want by selecting properties and then typing in the coordinates of their endpoints directly. Maybe you know that already.

Comment: Sorry, Altium is just not designed to be run from the keyboard alone. Closest I can give you is to use your favorite 2D CAD (Autocad or Draftsight) that supports keyboard entry to draw the board outline, than import it into Altium on a mechanical layer, then "Define Board Shape from Selected Objects".

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I don't think I'm being particular (just not clear) I don't mean I want a solution that completely excludes the mouse what I want is an option to type in the dimensions in a parameters box or something.

Comment: Again, sorry, but Altium just isn't designed that way. If the dimensions you want are reasonable whole numbers you can set the grid appropriately to make it easy to hit the size exactly (but you said you don't like this method); Or you can post-edit the vertex positions like mentioned in JYellon's answer. But AFAIK there's no way to enter the locations from the keyboard while creating the shape. It may be a stupid limitation, but if you're going to use Altium you need to get used to it having some stupid limitations.

Comment: Again thanks, I have previously used grid spacing as a work-around. Hopefully, the Altium devs implement something better in the future.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that Altium actually tracks your width and length in a properties window but you can't edit those properties.

Comment: There are a few other things you can do. You can lay down a point, then copy and paste it with an offset, then draw a line between the points. That spares you from having to add anything. Or you can draw the board outline starting at the origin so the coordinates are the same as the width and length of the PCB. After you draw it you can easily move it by doing a move selection by offset operation. Anyway, it is frustrating sometimes that the board dimensions are defined implicitly rather than explicitly.

Comment: There is an Altium webinar entitled "Tips & Tricks: Board Shape Creation" on 27 Feb 2020. You might be interested in attending or finding a recording of it should it be made available.

Comment: Altium have posted a video on this topic. I am linking it here for your convenience: https://youtu.be/vqHlxtV8lwE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a polygon (place polygon plane) on whatever layer you like. Mechanical 1 is a good choice since it is often used by Gerber export as the board outline layer. The "Outline Vertices" shown in the object properties when it is selected will allow you to specify exact values. When done, select `Design` > `Board Shape` > `Define from Selected Objects`. *(Tested in Altium 19.1.8)*

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped there was a better way of doing this but it appears the best way is to use Define from selected objects.